# looking for technique or utility that converts dir /s to index.html

Tags: dos, dir

I am looking for technique or utility that converts dir /s to index.html. I have 1000+ documents that I want to index quickly for the front page of a CD.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like the following:

```
   @echo off
   (
      echo ^<html^>
      echo    ^<head^>
      echo       ^<title^>CD Directory^</title^>
      echo    ^</head^>
      echo    ^<body bgcolor="white" text="blue"^>
      echo       ^<h1^>Directories^</h1^>

      for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /s') do (
         echo       ^<a href="file://%%a"^>%%a^</a^>^<br^>
      )

      echo    ^</body^>
      echo ^</html^>
   )>index.html
```

Copy and paste the code into Notepad and save it as a batch file say, *MAKHTML.BAT*. Then fire up a DOS dox and run the batch file by entering it's name ie,

```
   makhtml
```

This will produce a file named INDEX.HTML in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

AWK is good for this kind of processing.

You write a program (in some ways it's more like a script) and call up the AWK interpreter, and it runs your program either by interpreting it or by automatically compiling it, and processes input and generates output.

You used the MS-DOS tag so if you're after a version of AWK that runs under real MS-DOS, google "Rob Duff's AWK".

Otherwise there are lots of AWK packages and resources at http://www.klabaster.com/freeware.htm

AWK documentation says a lot about pattern matching and AWK-specific structure, but you can ignore that. An AWK script can look pretty much like a normal C program. There are three parts to it - a BEGIN clause, which is stuff that's done before the input file (directory list) is processed, and an END clause (have a guess :-) and a section that's executed for each line in the input file. Nicely suited to your application.

The BEGIN and END part of your AWK program would output the HTML tags necessary, like the title, and the base text including headings etc, and finish up the HTML document. The AWK print command sends text to the output, which you redirect to a file called index.html.

To process the lines from the dir /s file, and generate the body of the HTML document with the links, you would probably have to write some functions to parse the directory list and work out the tree arrangement. It depends on exactly how you want the index.html list to be arranged. AWK supports functions just like C.

I'd recommend using dir /s /b instead of just /s because the results will be much easier to parse.